# how to print "Hello [your_name]" in output screen of python?

Tags: python

"" these quotes are included in python's basic structure.
What if we want output with these quotes like I mentioned in question?

Comment: use escape character \ before the quotes

Comment: Use single quotes outside.

Comment: `print('"Hello [your_name]"')`

Answer (score 4):

Quotes are exchangeable in python, meaning that you can use single ones inside double ones and viceversa:

```
print("'Hi!'")
'Hi!'
print('"Hi!"')
"Hi!"
```

or use scape characters:

```
print("\"Hi!\"")
"Hi!"
```

Answer (score 0):

So Python prints everything inside the quote marks. So... if you want your string to be "hello [your name]" you need to put that inside the quotation marks to print it.

it would look like this.

```
print(""hello [your name]"")
```

and your string would be "hello [your name]"

Answer (score 0):

You can use double qoutes inside the single qoutes .
Try the below code !

**Code :**

```
name="Muhammad Usman"
print('"Hello ' + name + '"')
```

**Output :**

```
"Hello Muhammad Usman"
```